# Whys is my MySQL query returning rows, but no values?

Tags: mysql, xml, file-io

I'm using this query:

```
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE '\\MC_Library_Video.xml' INTO TABLE video ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<Item>';
```

On this XML file (abbreviated)

```
    <Item>
<field name="Filename">V:\13 Assassins\13 Assassins.mkv</field>
<field name="Name">13 Assassins</field>
<field name="File Type">mkv</field>
<field name="Genre">Adventure; Drama; Foreign; Martial Arts</field>
<field name="Date">40662</field>
<field name="Bitrate">7501</field>
<field name="Image File">13 Assassins.jpg</field>
<field name="Media Type">Video</field>
<field name="File Size">7041096346</field>
<field name="Duration">7509</field>
<field name="Date Created">1322620528</field>
<field name="Date Modified">1322620528</field>
<field name="Date Imported">1348075046</field>
<field name="Keywords">...</field>
<field name="Description">...</field>
<field name="Media Sub Type">Movie</field>
<field name="Sample Rate">48000</field>
<field name="Channels">6</field>
<field name="Bit Depth">16</field>
<field name="Compression">mkv video (video: AVC1, audio: DTS Audio)</field>
<field name="Width">1280</field>
<field name="Height">528</field>
<field name="MPAA Rating">R</field>
<field name="Director">Takashi Miike</field>
<field name="Actors">...</field>
<field name="Gross Revenue">$17,054,213</field>
<field name="Budget">$6,000,000</field>
<field name="FPS">23.9760400000000012</field>
<field name="Genres">Adventure; Drama; Foreign; Martial Arts</field>
</Item>
```

And I'm getting this result:

> 285 row(s) affected Records: 285  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0

But when I look at the data for the table (SELECT * FROM media.video;) I get nothing.  There's no data there.  Am I missing something?  The result makes it appear as if the data was read in, but the table is still blank.

Comment: What is this `285 deleted` part?  Something appears to be deleting the rows as you add them.

Comment: does this query run alone? if not check your other queries... it seems you are deleting some stuff here.. the error message is quite clear.

Comment: What does the table definition look like? It's really hard to guess what's happening without seeing the table definition.